# Finding an identity to solve $\cos t - 2 \cos (2t) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

On my examws I'm allowed to use this [formula paper](http://havovwo.nl/vwo/vwb/bestanden/vwb15ifor.pdf), and I have a question regarding the trigonometry rules all the way at the bottom of the paper. The rule says:

$$\cos t - \cos u = -2\sin\left(\frac{t + u}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{t - u}{2}\right) .$$

Now by answering a math question I came with this:

$$\cos t - 2 \cos (2t) = 0 .$$

Now if I could rewrite this as $a b = 0$, I could conclude that $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.

But how can I use the trigonometry rule now, as there is $-2$ in front of $\cos$? Would I get something like this?

$$\cos t - 2\cos u = -4\sin\left(\frac{t + u}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{t - u}{2}\right)$$

Comment: You need a different formula, also on your sheet $\cos 2t=2\cos^2t-1$. That gives you a quadratic in $\cos t$.

Comment: "t+u÷2" looks strange.  Do you mean (t+u)/2 or t+ u/2?  In any case, you can use the fact that $cos(2t)= cos^2(t)- sin^2(t)= 2cos^2(t)- 1$ to write $cos(t)- 2cos(2t)= cos(t)- 4cos^2(t)- 2= 0$ or $4cos^2(t)- cos(t)+ 2= 0$, a quadratic equation for cos(t).

Comment: No, your are not allowed to change the rules "at will".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to rewrite the second term using the double angle identity $$\cos 2 t = 2 \cos^2 t - 1,$$ which gives the equation
$$\cos t - 2 (2 \cos^2 t - 1) = 0.$$
Expanding (and canceling a sign for presentation) gives
$$4 \cos^2 t - \cos t - 2 = 0 ,$$
which is a quadratic in $\cos t$, so it can be analyzed using the Quadratic Formula.

Comment: wow in my 3 years of math I've never seen a solution like this. Using the Quadratic Formula to solve a quadratic in cos. Thank you for this solution i couldn't have thought of this my self.

Comment: This trick is occasionally useful, including for solving "biquadratic" equations $a x^4 + b x^2 + c = 0$ and equations of the form $a x^r + b + c x^{-r} = 0$.

Comment: (And you're welcome.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply your formula as you want to, you can do the following:
$$\cos t=2\cos 2t\iff\frac{\cos t}{2}-\cos 2t=0$$
Now consider the right triangle of legs $\cos t$ and $\sqrt{4-\cos^2 t}$,(the corresponding hypotenuse is equal to $2$). This way you have the angle $\theta$ you need: it is adjacent to the leg $\cos t$ (*you have by construction 
$\frac{\cos t}{2}=\cos \theta$*) and you get $$\cos \theta-\cos 2t=-2\sin \left(\frac{2t+\theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2t-\theta}{2}\right)=0$$
You can now find out the solution as you want to do.

Comment: hmm but what value does theta have or is it a unknown value like t? I've never  used it before .

Comment: You said you want to use the formula $\cos t - \cos u = -2\sin\left(\frac{t + u}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{t -  u}{2}\right)$ so I give you the way: you have $\cos \theta=\frac{\cos t}{2}$ and $\sin \theta=\frac{\sqrt{4-\cos^2 t}}{2}$. Take now your $a$ or $b$ equal to $0$.